# Fast algorithm for max-convolution with concave functions?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, discrete-mathematics

I'm interested in a discrete max-convolution problem, which is to compute
$$r(c) =  \max_{x | x \ge 0, \sum_k x_k = c} \left[ \sum_{k=1} f_k(x_k) \right] $$
for all values $c=0, \ldots, C$, where $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ is a vector of non-negative integers.

If we assume that $f_k$ are all concave functions i.e., $f(i+1) - f(i) \le f(i) - f(i-1)$, how efficiently can $r = (r(0), \ldots, r(C))$ be computed?

Follow-up: what if $J$ of the $f_k$ functions are not concave?

Comment: Possibly relevant paper: http://www.gams.com/~bussieck/TR-93-01.pdf

Comment: @dan_x are you still interested for an answer? Did you manage to find one that would like to share with us?